# Adjust a script to get only certain rtvscand output report

Tags: shell-script

I have the following working script:

```
for i in `cat list` ; do 
  ssh root@$i "uname -n ; cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ; service rtvscand status ;  echo ....................................................................." ; 
done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`
```

It produces the output that look like:

```
server1.local
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20150824.003
CurDefs=20150826.002
rtvscand is running
.....................................................................
server2.local
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20150609.001
CurDefs=20150610.004
rtvscand is not running
.....................................................................
server3.local
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20150607.001
CurDefs=20150608.004
rtvscand is running
.....................................................................
```

However, I want the output to only show the servers that have rtvscand running.  In other words, I want the output to look exactly like:

```
server1.local
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20150824.003
CurDefs=20150826.002
rtvscand is running
.....................................................................
server3.local
[DefDates]
LastDefs=20150607.001
CurDefs=20150608.004
rtvscand is running
.....................................................................
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take decison based on the output of `service rtvscand status` :

```
[ "$(service rtvscand status)" = 'rtvscand is running' ] && do_what_you_want
```

This means if the output of `rtvscand is running` is `rtvscand is running` then we will do some stuffs, otherwise not.

So your script can take the form :

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
   ssh root@"$name" '[ "$(service rtvscand status)" = "rtvscand is running" ] && \
                      { uname -n; cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ;}'
done <list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did that and got the following error.

Comment: bash: line 0: [: too many arguments

Comment: Here is what the program,

Comment: cat testing.sh
while IFS= read -r name; do
    ssh root@"$name" '[ "$(service rtvscand status)" = 'rtvscand is running' ] && \
                      { uname -n; cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ;}'
done <list.txt

Comment: I appreciate any information you can share with me.

Comment: @tester787 check my edits..